# Kontsevich invariant of surface knot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Kontsevich defined knot invariants by iterated integrals in the first half of 1990s in

M. Kontsevich, Vassiliev's knot invariants, Adv. Sov. Math., 16(2) (1993) 137-150.

After that Le, Murakami and Ohtsuki defined powerful invariant for 3-manifold by using the method of Kontsevich integral.

Polyak defined integral type invariant for curves in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4288.pdf

On the other hand, it seems that such kind of integral are not known for locally flatly embedding of closed surface in $R^4$ i.e.  surface knot.

Does anyone know surface knot invariants by configuration integrals ? 
(Except linking number)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references:

- [Rossi, C. A. (2002).](https://www.zora.uzh.ch/id/eprint/35446/) Invariants of higher-dimensional knots and
  topological quantum field theories *(Doctoral dissertation,
  Universität Zürich, Institut für Mathematik)*.
- [Cattaneo, A. S., & Rossi, C. A. (2005).](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00220-005-1339-0) Wilson surfaces and
  higher dimensional knot invariants. *Communications in mathematical
  physics, 256(3), 513-537.*
- [Watanabe, T. (2007).](https://msp.org/agt/2007/7-1/p03.xhtml) Configuration space integral for long
  n–knots and the Alexander polynomial. *Algebraic & Geometric Topology,
  7(1), 47-92.*
- [Sakai, K. (2010).](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218216510008583) Configuration space integrals for embedding
  spaces and the Haefliger invariant. *Journal of Knot Theory and Its
  Ramifications, 19(12), 1597-1644.*
- [Sakai, K., & Watanabe, T. (2012).](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004111000429) 1-loop graphs and
  configuration space integral for embedding spaces. *Mathematical
  Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 152(3), 497-533.*

These papers are continuation rather of the approach of Bott-Taubes (see [Bott-Taubes](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.530750) and [Volic](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218216507005178)), than the Kontsevich integral for knots. However, the two can be seen as outcomes of 'picking two different gauges' for perturbative expansions in the Chern-Simons gauge theory (see [Labastida](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905057)). To my knowledge it is still an open problem if the two universal knot invariants are the same.

There are also some results using different techniques (manifold calculus and operads):

- [Arone, G., & Turchin, V. (2014).](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.gt/1513732795) On the rational homology of high-dimensional analogues of spaces of long knots. *Geometry & Topology, 18(3), 1261-1322.*
- [Arone, G., & Turchin, V. (2015).](https://doi.org/10.5802/aif.2924) Graph-complexes computing the rational homotopy of high dimensional analogues of spaces of long knots. *In Annales de l'Institut Fourier, Volume 65 no. 1, pp. 1-62.*

Here the formality of little-disks operads is used, and this is again very closely related to integrals over configuration spaces. To me its quite mysterios how exactly the two approaches are related.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will check them soon.

Comment: I guess your question was specificly asking for the case of surface knots, some of these results apply in that case, some don't.

Comment: In Watanabe' s paper, his configuration integral for surface knot coincide invariant of Haboro and Shima. It sounds interesting.

Comment: I couldn't find any examples for calculation of Watanabe's configuration integral. I want to know examples, such as two twist spun trefoil ... and so on.